# I am trying to create a virtual environment but its not working. even it exists there

Tags: django, virtualenv

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZJX3.png)

I tried at least 20 times but didn't work
getting this error.
activate : The term 'activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1

- activate
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Suggestion [3,General]: The command activate was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\activate". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
PS C:\djangopracticeset\main\mainenv\scripts>

Answer (score 0):

When you are using windows powershell try this:

```
.\Activate.ps1
```

You have to be in the Scripts directory

Comment: I Tried this but not working 